# Code fires too fast

Tags: javascript, custom-button

With a lot of help from the forum over the past week, I have a custom button that performs a series of functions on the Opportunity object

1. It copies 6 fields to six custome fields
2. It clears the 6 fields
3. It copies all Opportunity Line Items to a Custom field
4. It deletes all Opportunity Line Items

It seems like item 4 sometimes fires before 3 has completed so, the Opportunity line Items never make it into the custom field.

Realizing I'm a noob, is there an easy remedy? Maybe have a message box popup with a button that fires the code for Item 4 on it?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';

record.Sample_Generate__c = '{!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c}'; 
record.Sample_Primary_Contact__c='{!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Primary_Contact__c}';
record.Sample_QB_Error__c ='{!Opportunity.AVSFQB__QB_Error__c}';
record.Sample_Quickbooks_ID__c='{!Opportunity.AVSFQB__Quickbooks_Id__c}';
record.Sample_QuickBooks_ItemType__c='{!Opportunity.AVSFQB__QuickBooks_ItemType__c}';
record.AVSFQB__Generate_Object__c = null;
record.AVSFQB__Primary_Contact__c = null;
record.AVSFQB__Product_Name__c = null;
record.AVSFQB__QB_Error__c = null;
record.AVSFQB__Quickbooks_Id__c = null;
record.AVSFQB__QuickBooks_ItemType__c = null;

var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");

var strProductNames = '';
for(var i=0; i<retriveOpptyLineItems.records.length ; i++){
strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}

//eliminate the last ','
if(strProductNames.length>0){
strProductNames = strProductNames.substring(0,strProductNames.length-1);
}
record.Samples_Sent__c = strProductNames;

var lineItems = sforce.connection.query("select id from opportunitylineitem where opportunityid = '{!Opportunity.Id}'")
var oliIds = []
var qri = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(lineItems)
while(qri.hasNext())
    oliIds.push(qri.next().Id)
sforce.connection.deleteIds(oliIds)

sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: What does the code look like? Are there @future methods involved in step 3/4?
You might need to lock the records to prevent concurrent editing by multiple users.

Comment: It's doing this in javascript with connection.js?  Can you post the code?

Comment: Should my question be moved?

Comment: This code is synchronous - it executes in order. However, it's still possible that something is going wrong in the product names section - some string error or something else - use the console to log out what is happening and test.

Comment: @Stavros Your question does belong here, I just fixed your tags for you. That said, it appears your code is indeed synchronous, but I feel you're not exactly going about it the right way. Have you considered a Flow, Web Service, REST call, trigger, Process Builder, anything to make it easier to maintain?

Comment: @sfdcfox. I havent considered those options because I dont know anything about them. This is my first sfdc coding rodeo and it seemed easiest to put everything on the button.

Comment: @Stavros We all started somewhere, of course. I suggest you investigate a few options, such as the one I put in my answer, as an alternative to using pure JavaScript. At minimum, you need more error checking, because you're probably losing data simply because an update failed to occur. This is in the documentation, so you might want to take a moment to look at it and see if a failed update is the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not error checking, I believe the disconnect occurs because the sforce.connection.update failed, possibly because there were too many items in the text field, a validation rule, or something else that caused the update to not go through.

Personally, I would consider making the entire transaction atomic (meaning, it can either all succeed or all fail, but not "half-way"). You could easily build this in to a web service call, for example:

```
global class MyWS {
    webservice static Object moveLinesToCustomField(Id opportunityId) {
        // do logic here
    }
}
```

Which would simplify your JavaScript to just:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js")}
var result = sforce.apex.execute("MyJS", "moveLinesToCustomField", { opportunityId: "{!Opportunity.Id}" });
if(!result.success) {
    alert("Error: "+result.message);
} else {
    window.top.location.reload();
}
```

Otherwise, consider *updating the opportunity first*, and then performing the deletion *only on success*. That's the most important part; make sure that your update happened successfully before attempting to delete the line items.